# How to fully initialize Angular2 page on page load (ngOnInit)

Tags: javascript, html, validation, angular

I'm having this peculiar problem I can't find the solution to online.

I have code that is along the following lines:

```
export class SRegister {
  http: Http;

  email: Control;
  password: Control;

  sregister: ControlGroup;

  constructor(http: Http, private router: Router, private builder: FormBuilder) {
    this.http = http;
    this.router = router;

    this.email = new Control('', Validators.required);
    this.password = new Control('', Validators.required);

    this.sregister = builder.group({
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("sreg_email"));
  }
```

This is part of my HTML code:

```
<span class="input_wrapper">
  <label for="sreg_email">Email:</label>
  <input class="input_field" type="text" id="sreg_email" autofocus="autofocus" ngControl="email" />
  <div *ngIf="email.dirty && !email.valid" class="errors_wrapper">
    Email invalid.
  </div>
</span>
```

This all works fine, the message goes away if I type in something, and comes back when I delete it.

The only problem is, whenever I initially load my page, or access this page through routing, the first letter I type in any textbox on my page gets cancelled out - nothing seems to happen. After that, if I check the console, I will notice that `ngOnInit` ran - I received the `console.log` output.

I'm not too sure how to fix this, and I'm glad to post more code if needs be.

Is this a documented issue?

Comment: Did you try this in ngAfterViewInit rather than ngOnInit?

Comment: @echonax I did, no difference at all, fmpov.

Comment: @echonax I'm not too worried about the output from `ngOnInit` - I just want the form fields to be properly initialized when I load the page, so I don't have to initialize them myself by triggering an `input` event, or whatever it was that then triggered `ngOnInit`.

Comment: That might be related to `autofocus`. Have you tried clicking into the input before writing something? I'm sure this is not related to page initialization in general. There is just something interacting weirdly.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Nope, I just tested - I removed `autofocus`, then I clicked into the box manually - `ngOnInit` still didn't trigger. The first letter I typed was still captured by the computer, and `ngOnInit` triggered.

Comment: Is this a dynamically injected component?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I just did another test. After removing `autofocus`, I clicked inside, and then back out - after doing that, `ngOnInit` triggered.

Comment: @echonax Sorry I'm not sure what you mean, but I'm pretty sure it's just a standard component accessed via a route?

Comment: That sounds very weird. `ngOnInit()` is called during component creation, not when you click somewhere or enter some test. The problem is probably in some part of your application that can't be derived from the content of your question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer How would you suggest I fix this? I can post more code if needs be.

Comment: It would be ideal if you could create a Plunker from this template https://plnkr.co/edit/pPe5um?p=info or just or menu `new` > `AngularJS` > `2.0.x (TS)`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Here's the link to the online version, though it is in Chinese: http://www.tuotr.com/new_student

Comment: No idea what I should do with this. I would need a minimal example that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111122/discussion-between-think123-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer If you take a look at the link, clicking on any of the textboxes and then typing will result in one character being missed.

Comment: Yeah, but I won't debug the compiled JS af a complete application. What I think is necessary is a minimal example to reproduce the issue, stripped by all code that isn't necessary to reproduce in a plunker that allows me to investigate it locally.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Here https://plnkr.co/edit/dZVOs17iK7EuBGB52Ki7?p=preview

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer There are errors in the plunker, I'm not sure how to fix them.

Comment: What error do you get. I don't get any, but I also can't reproduce the problem.